# SSRS query data partially missing from report

Tags: matrix, filter, ssrs-2008, visibility, query-designer

I know a variation of this questions has been asked 100 times but I've tried all options that I an find and wonder if there's something I'm missing.  I've tried many of the proposed solutions but can't get it to work.

I have a matrix report in SSRS 2013...parameters, datasets all the normal stuff.  The datasets are SQL stored procedures.  My matrix uses a dataset called dsDetails that pulls from on of the SQL stored procedures.  When I run the SP in SQL Server I get all the data I expect (i.e. data through year 2018); and if I run the SP through SSRS Query designer I also see all of the data.  However when my report renders some of the data isn't there (specifically I'm missing 2018 data; 2016 and 2017 data is present).  I've deleted the rdl.data file and cleared out cache and still can't get my data in.  I also checked that the missing data doesn't have any weird formatting and that also isn't the issue.

I've gone through and checked for matrix filters, row/column group filters, row/column goup visibility and so on.  I can find what's causing it...it seems like it has to be a filter or visibility.

So I decided to just drop a new matrix into the report and try and rebuild by just adding a sinlgle row and a single column and same deal...missing data for year 2018.  Is there a form of filter that applies to the report body (and therefore any matrix/table I drop in there).  This new matrix definitely has no filters or visibility added so it's a pure representation of the data...except it's missing 2018 data I clearly see in the query/dataset results.

Comment: The only filter that should apply would be the filter on the dataset. You get all data from the **Query Designer** view in the dataset properties which would include parameters but it doesn't filter for the items in the DataSet **Filters** in the dataset properties. But you sound like you know what you're doing and probably checked that. Try creating a new report with just the query and a table to see if you get 2018. ¯ \ _(ツ)_/¯